# Swift inconsistent warning: Result of call to 'xxx' is unused, where xxx is a function returning Void

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the following class:

```
class CachedObject: Decodable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    
    ...
    static func cached(id: Int) -> Self? {
        // Returns an object from a cache
    }

    // Load object from the server
    static func fetch(id: Int, detail: Int=1, handler: @escaping ((Self?) -> Void)) {
        guard id > 0 else {
            handler(nil)
            return
        }
        if let object = cached(id: id) {
            // The object is in the cache
            if object.detail < detail {
                // Reload the object
                object.reload(detail: detail, handler: handler)
                return
            }
            handler(object as? Self)
            return
        }
        // Do something
    }
    
    // Reload existing object
    func reload(detail: Int=1, handler: @escaping ((Self?) -> Void)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

It gives the following warning on the call of object.reload():
**Result of call to 'reload(detail:handler:)' is unused**
But this function returns Void.

If I force it with @discardableResult, I get the following warning:
**@discardableResult declared on a function returning Void is unnecessary**
And the previous warning is still here.

I used to silence this warning with:
_ = object.reload(detail: detail, handler: handler)
But since Swift 5, if I do that, the **compiler fails with nonzero exit code**, with the following logs:

```
11. While type-checking expression at [/Users/xxx/Xcode/xxx/Shared/Model/CachedObject.swift:71:17 - line:71:67] RangeText="_ = object.reload(detail: detail, handler: handler"
12. While type-checking-target starting at /Users/xxx/Xcode/xxx/Shared/Model/CachedObject.swift:71:17
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
```

Anyone having issues with using "_ = " since Swift 5?
Note that I also have the same compiler error somewhere else, where I use { _ in } as an argument to a function.

And why does Swift consider that my function *reload* is supposed to return a value, in the first place?

Comment: Replace void with ()

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. – The crashing compiler is definitely a bug.

Comment: See https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/57668. According to the comments you must not use `Self` as parameter type. Try to replace it by the actual type `CachedObject`

Comment: What do you think you’re doing with Self? If it’s Self, you wouldn’t need to cast it to Self. Why is the class not final?

Comment: CachedObject is an abstract class. I actually use subclasses of CachedObject and this is why I use Self as parameter type. Note that if I ignore the warnings, it works perfectly as intended. I used to silence the warnings with "_ = " before Swift 5, but now it gives me a compiler error.